# Mixin js file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am attempting to override this file

> \vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\js\view\form\element\email.js

**First** 
I create a `requirejs-config.js` file in

> C:\wamp64\www\magento222\app\code\BodyMod\EmailHide\view\frontend\

with the following content

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email': {
                'Vendor_Modul/js/email-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**Second**
I create an `email-mixin.js` file in

> C:\wamp64\www\magento222\app\code\BodyMod\EmailHide\view\frontend\web\js\

But it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js**:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/mixin/email-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/mixin/email-mixin.js**:

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    return function (Email) {
        return Email.extend({
            checkEmailAvailability: function () {
                console.log('test');
                return this._super();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

after this remember to regenerate static content :)